# Dúvida Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

estou aprendendo a programar utilizando EF, estou fazendo partindo do BD First, 
tenho um BD de outro projeto, e eu gostaria de criar uma solução baseada nesse bd, decidi partindo bem tranquilho, começando com uma lista de uma determinada tabela X, minha dúvida é: preciso criar minhas classes models com o mesmo nome das tabelas do banco? ou seja no meu banco existe uma tabela Estabelecimento e no projeto uma classe Establishment que é a representação dessa tabela, ou não tem problema?

Comment: E porque aprender com algo que já é obsoleto?

Comment: e qual tecnologia vc indicaria amigo?

Comment: A pergunta é um pouco confusa, porque você usa o EF Core, esta deveria ser usada, mas ele não tem DB First, então não está usando ela.

Comment: o db first foi a forma que eu quis dizer que estou fazendo o projeto utilizando a estrutura de um bd pronta como base do negocio, da mesma forma eu poderia fazer o projeto utilizando o code first, neste caso estaria criando o bd baseado nas minhas classes de negocio(models), utilizando as migrations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa que o nome das suas classes sejam iguais aos nomes das tabelas, mas você precisa mapear a classe para a tabela.

Exemplo de código do `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Estabelecimento>(cfg => 
    {
        cfg.ToTable("Establishment"); //para identificar o nome da tabela
        cfg.Property(e => e.Nome).HasColumnName("Name"); // para identificar o nome da coluna
    });
}
```

Comment: fiz aqui uns testes e deu certo, ainda ontem quando fiz a pergunta, eu testei mudar os nomes das classes com o mesmo do bd e o atributos da mesma forma, deu certo igualmente... nesse caso utilizando o OnModelCreating, eu teria que mapear cada classe e seus atributos de acordo com o bd?